# How to find unused CSS from rails? deadweight not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As the title says, I want to 'purify' the CSS of my rails application, to find unused CSS selectors.

I found a gem called deadweight but is too old. I can't even install it today (Dependencies failing)

So, is there another or actual way to clean the CSS? or an alternative to deadweight?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: With just a little of javascript in your code, it is impossible for the machine to ever tell which css selector is being used and which is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there is a good reason why you shouldn't be looking for such a tool - javascript. Even though, given selector might not exist in your templates, you might have some javascript which will add a class to one DOM element, an attribute to another and you might have another rare case which will add another class to another element or move it complete somewhere else inside the DOM.

To actually find whether your CSS selector exists or not, your tool would need to render all your templates and keep executing random js events until given selector shows off - and it will need to be able to tell whether it is ever gona find it. This is a halting problem, proved to be computable impossible to solve.

That being said, you can always use tools like the one listed on other answers - they might give you a list of suspicious selectors, however you will need to spend significant amount of time with every single one of them to find if there is a single case in your application when it can actually be used.

Word of warning: `DustMe` crawl the website through all the links on your page to get a better view of whole website - you don't use `link_to ..., method: <post|delete|put>`, do you?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few other solutions that might be worth trying:

[dust me selector Firefox add on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/)

[Helium Tool](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css)